# Why Xml file is not recognized in this XNA project?

Tags: .net, xml, windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

Why Xml file is not recognized in this XNA project? It is showing error as XML is not in intermediate format. Did I placed this XML file in correct path?[image]

Answer (score 5):

By default, XNA attempts to process XML content files into objects using its [Intermediate Serializer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/08/12/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-intermediateserializer.aspx).  This requires the XML files to follow a specific format, as described in that article.

If you want to manually process XML files, set the build action to **None** and tell it to **Copy if newer**.  That will output the XML file directly into the output directory without performing any Content Pipeline processing on it.  You can then open it as a stream using the `TitleContainer` class.

Alternatively, you could write your own content importer to process XML files in this format and then load them as you normally would through a `ContentManager`.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447754.aspx) describes how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The **Build Action** for the XML file is set to something other than what Sprite Vortex needs (most likely "Content")

[image]

Right click on the XML file, select properties, and check "Build Action".

Comment: I believe SpriteVortex just generated the XML files, so I don't think it's relevant here.  XNA content files need to be set to __Compile__ if they're being sent through the Content Pipeline, and __None__ if they're going to be processed manually.

Comment: @ColeCampbell: Could very well be.  I'm not familiar with XNA development, but this type of error in VS is usually caused by a file having an incorrect build type.  Not sure *what* the build type should be, however.  Looks like you do, so a +1.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot says "Missing XnaContent root element." Any chance that XNA needs this root element and your file doesn't provide it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<XnaContent xmlns:Graphics="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics" xmlns:Framework="Microsoft.Xna.Framework">

...

</XnaContent>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604979.aspx